# The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists in eclipse

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have downloaded the project just to see how things work but it shows this error although I think the mapping is fine.Any help would be appreciated. I am running it on localhost using tomcat 8080 with url -http://localhost:8080/HotelReservation/

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>


        enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem many times.

The solution I am currently using is whether the `webapp` (or the folder where you kept the views like jsp) is under deployment assembly.

Try this:

Right click on the project > `Build Path` > `Configure Build path` > `Deployment Assembly` > `Add`(right hand side) > `Folder` > (add your jsp folder, by default it is `src/main/webapp`)

Note: If you have another folder named `pages` under `webapp` which have the jsp files, say like  `src/main/webapp/pages`, then you have to include that too in the build path.